# PDO execute array - is it safety?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

```
 $sql = "UPDATE cvs SET     `email` = ?, `fname`=?, `education`=?, `from`=?, `to`=?,      `experience`=? WHERE cv_id = ?";
 $data = array_values($data);
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute($data);
```

So, is it safety? I have array and bind all values through execute. I'm using PDO.

Is it real binding or have to use special function like [php prepared statements with an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178926/php-prepared-statements-with-an-array)

Comment: Answer this question yourself. Provide justification. Is it "safe"? If so, why so? If not, why not? (Also, make sure to define "safe".)

Comment: Instead of `?`, I would use named parameters like `:email`.  What if `$data` is in the wrong order?  Then you would make sure `$data` was an associative array, with `"email"` as the key.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in safety between passing all the parameters as an array to `execute`, or using `bindParam` or `bindValue`.

I recommend using named parameters instead of `?`, to avoid being tied to the specific order of the columns in the query. This makes it easier to modify the query.

Answer (score 1):

They are all safe but the difference is `execute()` just bind the params as strings, you cannot specify the data types or length.

`BindParam()` and  `BindValue()` you can be explicit with the the types or length. So they could be helpful depending on what you would like to restrict in your parameters values.